# Why does my code doesn't display antything in a console

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python therefore my question might be stupid/easy. When i run this code I dont see any answer even though that python is not suggesting any errors. Anyone know why this happens like that?

```
number={2, 7, 11, 15}
a=len(number)
target=9

for i in range (a,1):
    b=target-number[i]
    print(b)
    for n in range(a):
        print(n)
        if n != a:
            if b==a[n]:
                print(b)
            else:
                print("jeszcze raz")
        else:
            print("liczby takie same")
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `range()`? What does `range(4, 1)` do? Reading the docs is a _very important part_ of learning any programming language.

Comment: `range(a, 1)` is an empty range.

Comment: `number` is a set, you can't index it with `number[i]`. I think you want a list.

Comment: `a[n]` makes no sense at all. `a` is a number, you can't index it. I suspect that should be `number[n]`

Comment: Yes, thank you, you were right. my oversight

Answer (score 0):

`range(a, 1)` is an empty range if `a` is bigger than `1`, so your outer for loop never runs. Assuming you want to count from `a` *down to* 1 (inclusive), consider

```
range(a, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot index a set

```
number = {2, 7, 11, 15}  
print(number[0])
```

-> TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Do it a tuple () or an array []

And you cannot iterate the integer **a**:

-> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable